# Explanation For code snippet (Structures)

Tags: c, pointers, structure, dereference

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct s
{
 int i ;
 struct s *p ; 
} ;

int main( )
{
 struct s var1, var2 ;
 var1.i = 100 ;
 var2.i = 200 ;
 var1.p = &var2 ;
 var2.p = &var1 ;
 printf ( "\n%d %d", var1.p -> i, var2.p -> i ) ;
 return 0;
}
```

I need to know something about this line:

```
printf ( "\n%d %d", var1.p -> i, var2.p -> i ) ;
```

Why is the arrow operator used and why is there only `i` after the arrow operator and not like this:

```
printf ( "\n%d %d", var1.p -> var2.i, var2.p -> var1.i ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks pac, i am wondering how to fix the synatx

Comment: I feel there is something missing here: `struct *p;`

Comment: yea right i missed the struct name my bad

Comment: You could very well edit your question.

Comment: Congratulations, you have created your first *circular* linked-list.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Is a *circular* linked-list used in any algorithm/application? I've seen using circular buffers (arrays and modulo) for many sliding windows things, but never with pointers.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Oh yes, the distinction is a *circular* list allows you to iterate from any position in the list to any position in the list across the head or tail nodes (as they are treated just as any other node). In a traditional head/tail list, if you are on say node 35, you can only iterate from that node to the beginning or end of the list -- but not across.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that's because `p->a` means `(*p).a`.

So think,

you want to get the struct pointed by `p` so you write `var1.p` but that's the pointer - so you dereference it to get the `struct`. `*(var1.p)`.

And then you have the other `struct` and you want to get its `i` variable. So you do

`*(var1.p).i` which is equivalently `var1.p->i`.

Also as alk pointed out - it is

```
struct s
{
 int i ;
 struct s *p ;
} ;
```

---

```
var2.p -> var1.i
```

This is illegal because `struct s` has no memnber called `var1`.

Answer (score 1):

`var1.p` is a pointer to struct s that points to `var2`. that means that `var1.p->i` is like `var2.i`

also, the `->` operator is like the `.` operator only you use the `->` for pointers to structures and `.` for structures.